# Apache ErrorDocument 400 https redirection without 302 found page with the actual link

Tags: redirect, https, http-status-code

When I force the error 400 by trying http on a https port I get a 302 found code with the https://myserver/mypage.html link I want to show, and I have to click it to get to the page

How can I skip this step and have a straight redirection to the https:// link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it could work by defining a static ErrorDocument eg:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /redirect_https.txt
```

and create the file redirect_https.txt in your document root with the following content:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://myserver/mypage.html
```

this works (even tried) and sends the browser a "faked" HTTP-redirect

Comment: Nice, man! Works sweet as a charm in every browser. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that 400/BadRequest is a bit special in this situation, because you are simply talking a wrong protocol to the server and what you get back isn't even a valid HTTP response (try: curl -i http://myserver:443/ .. there are no headers).

see also:
[Problems redirecting Error 400 Bad Request to custom page](https://serverfault.com/questions/158122/problems-redirecting-error-400-bad-request-to-custom-page)

Comment: Well yes. What is special is only one port is open through firewall and is https so when I get a http request to that address (which can be pretty common since people can forget to use https:// and just do mypublicIP:myopenport instead of https:// mypublicIP:myopenport) I would like to offer the posibility to seamlessly switch to https.