# ErrorDocument 400 redirect to different URL without rewrite

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, redirect, errordocument, 400

I want to implement a custom Error 400 page on my website `tikolu.net`, to a file called `400.php` in a folder called `error`.

The first thing I tried was to simply place `ErrorDocument 400 /error/400.php` into my `.htaccess` file. This doesn't work because for errors like 400, it cannot be handled by the `.htaccess` file and instead must be placed into the `httpd.conf` file, as mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/a/158156).

This works in the sense of being acknowledged by Apache, but it still does not fully work. The default message still displays, but this time with this added at the bottom: `Additionally, a 400 Bad Request error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

This is because `ErrorDocument` does not redirect, but instead just rewrites the URL, while now trying to show `400.php`. But because this is just a rewrite, Apache still thinks that the requested document was the same one which initially caused the error, so it results in an Error 400 again.

The furthest I managed to get is instead say `ErrorDocument 400 https://tikolu.net/error/400.php`. This works because Apache cannot rewrite the URL again (as it is an external one), and is forced to redirect. However, this won't work for me as I need to know the original URL which caused the error. I tried getting `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` from PHP but it is empty.

The `ErrorDocument` directive has access to some [variables](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html#variables), like `REDIRECT_URL` but they are only set if the target is internal, so it wouldn't work in this case.

Is there a possibility to use `ErrorDocument` but with a proper redirect, so that it can be handled by a PHP script, without repeating the error? If not, is there a way to use the directive's variables when being redirected to an external location?

---

Here are the contents of my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
IndexOptions +Charset=UTF-8

# REMOVE www FROM URL
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.tikolu.net'">
    RedirectMatch (.*) https://tikolu.net$1
</If>

# REDIRECT HTTP TO HTTPS
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'off'">
    RedirectMatch (.*) https://tikolu.net$1
</If>

# BLOCK .listing FILE
<Files ~ "\.listing$">
    Require all denied
</Files>

# DIRECTORY INDEXES
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

# ERROR DOCUMENTS
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.php

# REDIRECTS
```

(various redirects follow, all in the form `RewriteRule location$ /destination [L]`)

I have disabled my `.htaccess` file temporarily (by renaming it), and the problem still remains.

---

**EDIT:** I managed to find a slightly hacky (but working) workaround:

`ErrorDocument 400 '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/error/400.php">'`

Comment: How are you triggering the 400 response? What other directives do you have? "But because this is just a rewrite, Apache still thinks that the requested document was the same one which initially caused the error, so it results in an Error 400 again." - this isn't true. `400.php` is called via an _internal subrequest_ (not strictly a "rewrite", but similar). This triggers another internal request. If you are getting that additional message, then it would seem that the request to `400.php` is itself triggering a 400 error.

Comment: Check Apache's error log.

Comment: `ErrorDocument 400 400.php` - The target URL needs a slash prefix, otherwise it will be seen as literal text and it will simply output the string "400.php".

Comment: @MrWhite I'm triggering the 400 error by going to an invalid URL like `https://example.com/%`. I know that the target URL needs a prefix, I just used `400.php` as an example. In reality I say something like `ErrorDocument 400 /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/400.php`, and I can confirm doing exactly this, but for a 404, works.

Comment: and "What other directives do you have?" An error like this is often due to conflicts with other directives. Are you not using vHosts? FWIW, I have this working OK on my system. `/%` triggers the custom `ErrorDocument` defined in a vHost. I'm also using a URL-path relative to the document root, rather than absolute filesystem path. (The docs don't actually state that a filesystem path is permitted here?) Have you checked the error log, as Michael suggested?

Comment: That's the access log, not the error log. Check the error log.

Comment: @MrWhite this is the only vHost on my system, and the only other `ErrorDocument` directive's are for 404 and 403, in my `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The error log under `/var/log/apache2/error.log` doesn't mention the 400 error anywhere, I don't know am I checking it wrong or if there's another log that I am unaware of. The `access.log`, however, just states that /% was accessed, with no mention of the 400 error.

Comment: And you have no other directives... mod_rewrite, mod_alias, etc. in your vHost or `.htaccess` file(s)?

Comment: @MrWhite I have a few `RewriteRule`s configured in my `.htaccess`, but that's pretty much it.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the contents of your `.htaccess` file (please edit your question to add this information). Right now that is the most probable cause, so needs to be ruled out at least. Did you also try using a document-root relative URL-path in the `ErrorDocument` directive?

Comment: @MrWhite I've edited the answer to show my `.htaccess` file. I have tried a document-root relative URL path for the `ErrorDocument`, and everything is still the same.

Comment: "slightly hacky (but working) workaround" - and presumably you get the _requested_ URL from the `Referer` in this case? You seem to have covered all bases - I'm out of ideas. What platform and version of Apache 2.4 are you using? I only have access to Apache 2.4.7 on Windows to test at the moment (which, as I mentioned above, "works" in this regard). This could well be platform dependent as the OS certainly has an effect on how requests are mapped to the filesystem.